# link collections in python

Tags: python, scripting, collections

As simple as it is to link a collection with another one just by drag and drop I can't manage to find the way in python.

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
```

this seem to work only with objects, how would it be with collections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to link other collection under collection's children, not objects:

```
bpy.data.collections["Collection1"].children.link(bpy.data.collections["Collection2"])
```